# Resize an xfs-formatted logical volume group

Tags: centos, rhel, partition, xfs, alma-linux

My partitions currently look like this:

```
sda                  8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sda1               8:1    0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/storage
sdb                  8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk
├─sdb1               8:17   0    30M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2               8:18   0   270M  0 part /boot
└─sdb3               8:19   0 118.9G  0 part
  ├─almalinux-root 253:0    0  20.9G  0 lvm  /
  ├─almalinux-swap 253:1    0     3G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─almalinux-var  253:2    0    25G  0 lvm  /var
  └─almalinux-home 253:3    0    70G  0 lvm  /home
```

As you can see, the `sdb2` (i.e the `/boot`) partition is only 270 MB and I'm having problems upgrading kernel. I want to reduce my `almalinux-root` logical partition (and hence the whole `sdb3` volume group) by, say 200 MB, and add that to `sdb2`.

Both `sdb2` and `sdb3` have `xfs` filesystem installed.

I'm unable to do anything to it using `parted` or `fdisk`. Is there a way to shrink that partition non-destructively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems: XFS does not support shrinking, and even if it did, LVM does not support moving the start offset of a PV. So there is no room for `/dev/sdb2` to grow. So the thing you want, is not really possible to do. You can finagle it, but it's risky...

So what to do? You could...

- …ditch `/dev/sdb2` completely, move `/boot` back onto `/` and henceforth rely on Grub to support XFS on LVM. The then unused `/boot` partition could be merged into `/boot/efi` in case you ever need more leg room there.
- …delete (or shrink) the swap LV, `pvmove` other LVs away from the end of PV, shrink the PV, and finally create a new `/dev/sdb4` `/boot` partition at the end of disk.
- …backup everything onto your `/mnt/storage` or some other drive, and set things up any way you want from scratch.
- …shrink `/dev/sda1` (if it's not XFS but ext4 or some other filesystem that actually supports shrinking) and put `/boot` as `/dev/sda2`.
- …buy a cheap USB stick and use it as `/boot` and consider adding some Linux Live ISOs to it as well.

So there are some options. You should pick one you're confident in, rather than risk losing data to some complex method.

Comment: Among these, option 1 sounds best to me. Some searching around tells me that I don't really need a separate `/boot` partition. I don't on my regular devices, but I read somewhere that it's better to have it for server distros due for reliability or something. But looks like that info was outdated.

Comment: So, to summarize, I should just unmount `/boot` and copy the data from the old `/boot` drive to the `/boot` folder I now have? (and edit `/etc/fstab`, of course.) Are there any particular `rsync` flags that I should use for the copy?

Comment: `rsync -a` or just `cp -a`. You'll also have to reconfigure and reinstall Grub to make LVM-XFS work. Otherwise grub will keep looking for the old location - well, that would be possible as well (keep the old /boot around for Grub exclusively, with a menuentry pointing to LVM) but your distro would have to cooperate with a setup where Grub and /boot are separate things. Most systems expect these to be one unit.

Comment: I did all of it. Having some problems still. I think I need to change some config. I opened a new question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/718980/grub-searching-for-kernel-in-wrong-location).