# Grub searching for kernel in wrong location

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, grub2

I recently switched from a separate `/boot` partition to using just the folder `/boot`. The problem I'm facing is that while booting, `grub` searches for the kernel at `/vmlinuz...` instead of `/boot/vmlinuz`. Manually editing the grub entry to replace `($root)/vmlinuz...` with `($root)/boot/vmlinuz...` lets me boot temporarily.

I've tried doing `grub2-mkconfig` but that doesn't help. My system is AlmaLinux 9.

I want to know what to do in order to fix this issue i.e. so that running `grub2-mkconfig` generates the proper boot entries, with proper kernel locations?

I'm not sure which files to provide for this, but I'll provide any config files asked.

Edit: I think the solution might be changing the root for the grub boot environment to `{partition}/boot` but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Why separate /boot? Most desktops do not need it and then it is one more partition to manage space on. Do you have /boot as entry in fstab. The update/reinstall of grub would need that to know to use your new /boot partition.

Comment: @oldfred I used to have a separate `/boot` but no longer do.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually run `kernel-install` to fix the entries in `/boot/loader/entries/`.

The command I ran was `kernel-install add <kernel> /usr/lib/modules/<kernel>/vmlinuz`. I don't know why reinstalling the kernels didn't do it.